# Delete unused files and folders in an existing project

Tags: javascript, php, file, filesystems, directory

I recently started working on this php project that had some previous developers.
These dev's made a bit of a mess of things, resulting in a **huge amount** of different files, in PHP as well as javascript files and stylesheets.
I'd like to reduce the amount of files and folders, since they're now over `17k` and `5.4k` respectively.

Is there a way I could *flag* unused files for deletion?
Perhaps while navigating the site, e.g. **whitelisting** files that are being used?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sometimes its quicker to write things from scratch rather than work with "Megamoth" but if you need to keep it running you probably need to put it into some kind of version control system.

I recommend Git

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29

https://git-scm.com/

and just start refractoring it.

Version control system will keep your old code so you will be sure that you don't loose anything while deleting or changing your code and you will be able to jump from one version to another very quickly.

Comment: I work with Git on a daily basis for other, more professional projects.
I don't see Git could help me out here?
When I got on this project, it already had this ridiculous amount of files and no git tracking.

What would you suggest?

Comment: in git you don't need to actually mark files to delete if you are sure that file is no longer needed you just delete it and forget. If you will ever need that file back you can check it in git and see what it does and revert it back or fix the error. Plus using git you can create branches while refractoring this code, and step by step get this code more organised.

Comment: Basically refractoring involves many small and big changes to the code thus you need to control versions of this code, in my opinion git is very useful tool in that kind of tasks and you may find that you don't need anything more maybe except good editor or IDE.

Comment: Never thought about using Git that way. It seems like a good way to go!  
Thank you for your answer.